# Вставка картинки из Delphi в Excel

Tags: delphi, excel, vba

Для вставки картинки из Delphi использую `Excel.Selection.PasteSpecial('Рисунок', false, false)` 
Какие варианты параметра `format` можно использовать кроме `Рисунок`, для вставки изображения?

Comment: И что, вставляется? а то показанные параметры как-то не очень соответствуют тому, что описывается в справке по `Range.PasteSpecial Method`... см. напр. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel

Comment: Тут скорее подходит [Worksheet.PasteSpecial Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-pastespecial-method-excel). Согласно которому можно использовать вместо строкового указания формата вставляемых данных определенные константы

Comment: Вы про эти форматы (ppPasteBitmap, ppPasteJPG и т.п.) ?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212207%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Akina Вставляется. Я удивлен, почему не работает вариант Excel.Selection.PasteSpecial('Picture (JPEG)', false, false)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov У вас такой вариант работает?

Comment: @Anton Ваш - да.  Worksheet.PasteSpecial после плясок с бубном - тоже. У вас, как я понимаю, проблема "почему вставляет как битмап, а не как JPEG/PNG и т.п.?"

Comment: @ViktorTomilov проблема в том "почему вставляет как PNG, а не как JPEG, хотя в клипбоард вставляется именно JPEG"

Comment: @Anton Я могу ошибаться, но paste as JPEG появилось, начиная с 2003 офиса. Выше я привел ссылку на MSDN. Возможно, копать нужно оттуда.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov а подскажите, что за пляски с бубном, чтоб Worksheet.PasteSpecial работал)

Comment: @Anton Мелочи: по спецификации у него 7 параметров. У меня заработал лишь с шестью или тремя.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov заработал именно в контексте "paste as JPEG"?

Comment: @Anton Нет, только битмап

Comment: я всегда записывал  макрос, а потом его код смотрел :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, `Я удивлен, почему не работает вариант Excel.Selection.PasteSpecial('Picture (JPEG)', false, false)`, вероятно потому что `Selection` по сути это `Range`, а метод `PasteSpecial` у `WorkSheet` и `Range` отличаются существенно

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin Excel.Selection.PasteSpecial('Рисунок', false, false) - работает, разница только в строковом параметре. Раньше работало и с 'Picture (JPEG)'